# HttpClient SendASync crashes

Tags: c#, .net, autorest

I have a service that after my latest updates have started crashing.

It does crash on both the server and in my development environment, so it's not system specific.

It crashes on code generated by Autorest

```
_httpResponse = await HttpClient.SendAsync(_httpRequest, cancellationToken)
                                .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

It throws a StackOverFLowException and nothing is attached... There is no more info given.

Fiddler shows that no data is being sent, so it dosen't start sending anything.

As far as i can recall, the only change i did when it stopped working is i changed *another* autorest namespace out.

Comment: please show how you construct _httpRequest

Comment: @AdamStawarek I managed to solve it. But this comment would have helped, since it was a wrongfulle added header on the request that caused it!

Answer (score 0):

Actually managed to solve it myself.

I was trying to add an Accept-Header by using a delegate, this somehow created an infinite loop thus causing a StackOverflow.

The correct way of adding it is:

`Client.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));`

But i was adding it like this

`httpRequest.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");`

Easy mistake and very weird error message... ^^